# Wordpress Emails Only Being Received by Gmail

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

I have a very strange problem that I cannot find any solution to.

Some background: I have my domain hosted with ipage. All emails are hosted through ipage except for admin@domain.com which uses google mail business account. I have a wordpress site hosted on this domain which uses cloudflare.

The problem: The automated emails sent by the site (such as the woocommerce new order emails, or the wordpress forgot password link) are only being received by gmail accounts. In gmail, next to the sender, there is a red question mark and when I hover over it, it says "Gmail can't verify the domain actually sent this message". I'm guessing these emails are getting blocked somewhere before the final spam filter for other email accounts like AOL but no matter what I do I can't get the emails functioning everywhere, or the red question mark to disappear. I followed this link to setup cloudflare https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218069617-How-do-I-add-or-edit-mail-or-MX-records-. When I tried to follow this tutorial, as suggested by cloudflare, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168896-How-do-I-add-Google-Apps-MX-mail-records- all emails get routed to the gmail business email.

I suspect the problem has to do with cloudflare but when I asked them they were of no help. Does anyone know what I can do to have emails received everywhere, and not just with google?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible that the ip range used by your hosting provider could have a bad reputation associated with it from previous activity (or current activity) of another user using it for things such as spamming or data harvesting.

If this is the case it's likely your emails are being blocked at the Email Service Provider (ESP) rather than any spam or junk mail filters.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta [test your email spam score](http://www.mail-tester.com/). Really, the problem could be many things:

- someone on your shared hosting account blew up the shared IP with spam
- your WP mail settings are misconfigured
- DNS troubles (like you stated)

Email doesn't just disappear, it always goes somewhere... if it isn't your targeted audience inbox, maybe it's queued up by cPanel spam assassin or some other filter.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you use Cloudflare for DNS. This caused me some headaches about two weeks ago, so here is what fixed the issue for me:

1. Login to cloudflare and check if you domain has spf (TXT) record.
2. (This is available in Plesk I don't know where to find it if you use cPanel): Under mail settings, check this option - Send from domain IP addresses

Also check your outgoing mail queue to see if emails are being kept there. If so the steps above will definitely fix this issue.

Comment: Just noticed this: "Some background: I have my domain hosted with ipage. All emails are hosted through ipage except for admin@domain.com which uses google mail business account." - I'm not sure if this is OK, you either use Google for business for all emails or you don't use it at all.